# Bounty button shows incorrect number

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

While the button shows that there is 1 active bounty

[image]

clicking on it shows an empty page. The number of bounties is still 1

[image]

I must say that the bounty expired just a little time ago (can't tell exactly).

---

- Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m
- Windows 8.1

---

**UPDATE**

I refreshed the page a few times (and also closed and reopened the browser, if that matters), but the result is the same.

**UPDATE 2**

**Now** clicking on the button redirects correctly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv%20or%20opencv3.0?filter=bounties&sort=ending , while initially I was redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv?filter=bounties&sort=active&page=2. Since there is only 1 active bounty (so 1 page), I saw the empty page.

Clicking on the bounty button from the [&page=2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv?filter=bounties&sort=active&page=2) still doesn't send to the [correct page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv%20or%20opencv3.0?filter=bounties&sort=ending).

**UPDATE 3**

I figured out how I fall in this bug before. Here are the steps:

1. Start from this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv%20or%20opencv3.0 (bounty button works ok)
2. Go to second page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv%20or%20opencv3.0?page=2 (bounty button works ok)
3. Reload page: still on link of step 2, but I see the page from step 1. (bounty button doesn't work. It points to page 2).

So I guess that another bug is while reloading the webpage at step 3. I opened a  [new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309155/reload-webpage-on-page-2-shows-first-page-but-links-to-second) regarding this

Comment: I clicked on the `1 bounties` (sic) and got this, http://stackoverflow.com/q/33311153/1927206, a bounty with five days to run.

Comment: **Now** (after a few refresh, again) I can see that. Probably because initially I was redirected to the page #2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv?filter=bounties&sort=active&page=2 even if there was only one page.

Comment: @BillWoodger done. Thanks for the step-by-step support :D

Comment: I can reproduce. If I click on the `1 bounties` from page 2 (and presumably subsequent) of the questions for the opencv tag then I see what you see. Ah. See you got to that earlier :-) Good spot.

Comment: @BillWoodger since I was having again the error, I figured out how I fell into it the first time. Reloading the question webpage while I'm seeing page 2 shows me page 1, but the link is still to page 2, and bounty doesn't work. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).