# Reload webpage on &page=2 shows first page, but links to second

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

From the question webpage, if I go to the *second* page and refresh the browser, I see the *first* page, but the link in the browser is still on *second* page.

This will also produce a [bug with bounty button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309133/bounty-button-shows-incorrect-number?noredirect=1#comment264831_309133).

This is valid also for pages > 2.

---

How to reproduce the bug:

1. Start from a question page, e.g: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv%20or%20opencv3.0
2. Go to second page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv%20or%20opencv3.0?page=2
3. Refresh webpage. I see content from page 1, while the link shown in the browser is the same as page 2

---

- Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 m
- Windows 8.1

**UPDATE**

The issue seems caused by the missing `pagesize` parameter, which is automatically removed for me.

Comment: For me, going to page 2 changes the url `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv%20or%20opencv3.0?page=2&pagesize=50`, which works on refresh, but removing the `pagesize` reverts it to the page 1 data, so it seems like both page and pagesize are required. I imagine because without the pagesize it doesn't know where the page 2 data should start?

Comment: @TomHart copy&pasting your link sends me to page 1. I moved to page 2 using SO page navigation, so maybe a bug is also there, since it doesn't append `pagesize` to the link.

Comment: Hmm, copy-paste for me also goes to page one, but if I then tab to page 2, and refresh, I stay with the page 2 data. I'm using the same OS and Chrome version as you.

Comment: @TomHart I see page 1 even after tab to page 2 and refresh. The `pagesize` seems to be automatically removed from the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).